# FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android

In emulator (i use genymotion) it works fine, but when I run it on a real device (my phone is ASUS ZenFone Laser 5.0) throws a filenotfoundexception

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/cam20160926_075819.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

> imgBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

here's the method onActivityResult()

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                    Bitmap imgBitmap;
                    try {
                        imgBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                        accountPhoto.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong while taking a photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

i read some related questions and solutions about this EACCES, and it seems the problem is on my permission:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

am I missing something? thanks for responding

Comment: which version of SDK and android do you use?

Comment: I am in marshmallow 6.0 now api lvl 23. and my min sdk version of my app is  api lvl 18

Comment: so I can't see here your permission request about Read and write external storage ?

Comment: what? i dont understand what you're referring

Comment: What is imageUri? I think it is null. Please try to use parameter data in the function and check whether it null first before use. Use `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`. For details, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23868051/5241603

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "cam" + timeStamp +".jpg" );
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photo));
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

Comment: imageUri is not null

Comment: Check my answer in the below link. Hope it work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58797938/11696949

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to request permission before you start your instructions because this permission is considered dangerous in Marshmallow:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
     {
      requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RESULT);
     } 
    else
     {
    //your code
     }
```

Comment: where do i put this?

Comment: you put it before your instructions which use the the permission

Comment: im using fragment in this matter, i cant find the initialization of RESULT

Comment: initialize it as static int =1

Comment: Fortunately, it solved my problem. but i think this is not the best solution, still I will check this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` overrides the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` read permission. If you look into the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) you'll see that the former also permits reading from storage.

Try and remove the `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute and see if that works. I suspect that your device runs an SDK version > 18.

Check out this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270626/425238