# How do I read from my apps private internal storage?

Tags: java, android-bitmap

I am getting a strange `fileNotFoundException EACESS permission denied` message in the log.

I have read external memory permission. I can read from my `/storage/emulated/0/myscreenshots` directory but not from `/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files`.

I get the error message mentioned above when I attempt to do so. What is the problem here and how do I tackle it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" >
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name = "com.mycompany.myapp.MyService"
        android:enabled = "true"
        android:label="MyService"
        />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your manifest xml please?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" >
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <service
   android:name = "com.mycompany.myapp.MyService"
   android:enabled = "true"
   android:label="MyService"
   />
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: which version of android ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693082/filenotfoundexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied/39693408#39693408

Comment: I am using android 4.4.4(Honeycomb)

Comment: @John rather than putting manifest to comments, please edit your answer and add that there, also please format is as code (by putting 4 spaces to the left of each line)

Comment: Now I am getting this D message on the log,

Comment: D   skia com.mycompany.myapp                     --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null